# Understanding Django Class-based views mixins

Tags: python, django

What are mixins in Django Class Based View? How to start using this and when? Can anyone provide practical example which will allow me to understand it?

Answer (score 6):

Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/mixins/ ?

I'm not sure my example is relevant but it is a mixin I regularly use...

```
class OwnedObjectsMixin(object):

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.owner = self.request.user
        form.full_clean()
        if form.is_valid():
            return super(OwnedObjectsMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return super(OwnedObjectsMixin, self).form_invalid(form)

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.user_id = self.request.user.id
        return self.model.objects.filter(owner=self.user_id)


class MyModelList(OwnedObjectsMixin, ListView):
    model = myModel
```

Comment: Did it help? You havn't marked the question as answered so I guess it hasn't. Maybe you want to formulate your question again in a different way?